# TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frame_offset'

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I am new to using Pytorch library. I am trying to run the following code and get this type TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frame_offset'. Is there any solution for the code to complete training process?

```
import torch
import torchaudio
from torchaudio.datasets import TEDLIUM
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Set the path to the TedLium dataset
tedlium_path = 'D:/Download/TEDLIUM_release1'
train_dataset = torchaudio.datasets.TEDLIUM(root=tedlium_path,
                                              release = 'release1',
                                              subset = 'train',
                                              download = False,
                                              audio_ext = '.sph')

test_dataset = torchaudio.datasets.TEDLIUM(root=tedlium_path,
                                            release = 'release1',
                                            subset = "test",
                                            download = False,
                                            audio_ext = '.sph')
  

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                        batch_size=8,
                                        shuffle=False)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,
                                        batch_size=8,
                                        shuffle=False)

print("start")
for i, (inputs) in enumerate(train_loader):
    print(type(inputs))
```

The exception is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File ".\another.py", line 36, in <module>
    for i, (inputs) in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 633, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 677, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\datasets\tedlium.py", line 196, in __getitem__
    return self._load_tedlium_item(fileid, line, self._path)
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\datasets\tedlium.py", line 149, in _load_tedlium_item
    waveform, sample_rate = self._load_audio(wave_path + self._ext_audio, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time)
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\FL using socket\venv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\datasets\tedlium.py", line 171, in _load_audio
    return torchaudio.load(path, **kwargs)
TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frame_offset'
```